# In my react project os.networkInterfaces() return empty object,but console return correct result

Tags: node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Mxe.png)
1、I want to get local ip with  os.networkInterfaces(),bug when my project runed by **"npm start",**  os.networkInterfaces() return empty object .

2、If I touch a js file like: test.js , and  excute "node test.js" ,it will reture the correct result an array.  content:

```
   const os = require('os');
   console.log( os.networkInterfaces());
```

3、If run in cmd:

```
$node
$const os = require('os');
$ os.networkInterfaces();
```

it also returns the correct result.
It is so confusing to me